# is it possible create a model with more items than the json is?

Tags: android, json, server

I have a JSON that has 13 fields.But i create a model in java that has 15 fields.because i wanted to have a complete model and in future it will rise the fields in server side.is it wrong to do this?
My `json` is :

```
{
    "CMBL009001": "010001",
    "NMBL009002": 0,
    "CMBL009003": "",
    "CMBL009004": "",
    "CMBL009005": "",
    "CMBL009006": "",
    "NMBL009007": 0,
    "BMBL009008": 0,
    "NMBL009009": 0,
    "CMBL009010": "ADMIN",
    "CMBL009011": "",
    "NMBL009012": 2,
    "NMBL009013": 1
}
```

my class is :

```
public class NewUser implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("BMBL009008")
private Long mBMBL009008;
@SerializedName("CMBL009001")
private String mCMBL009001;
@SerializedName("CMBL009003")
private String mCMBL009003;
@SerializedName("CMBL009004")
private String mCMBL009004;
@SerializedName("CMBL009005")
private String mCMBL009005;
@SerializedName("CMBL009006")
private String mCMBL009006;
@SerializedName("CMBL009010")
private String mCMBL009010;
@SerializedName("CMBL009011")
private String mCMBL009011;
@SerializedName("NMBL009002")
private Long mNMBL009002;
@SerializedName("NMBL009007")
private Long mNMBL009007;
@SerializedName("NMBL009009")
private Long mNMBL009009;
@SerializedName("NMBL009012")
private Long mNMBL009012;
@SerializedName("NMBL009013")
private Long mNMBL009013;

protected NewUser(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mBMBL009008 = null;
    } else {
        mBMBL009008 = in.readLong();
    }
    mCMBL009001 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009003 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009004 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009005 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009006 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009010 = in.readString();
    mCMBL009011 = in.readString();
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mNMBL009002 = null;
    } else {
        mNMBL009002 = in.readLong();
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mNMBL009007 = null;
    } else {
        mNMBL009007 = in.readLong();
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mNMBL009009 = null;
    } else {
        mNMBL009009 = in.readLong();
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mNMBL009012 = null;
    } else {
        mNMBL009012 = in.readLong();
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        mNMBL009013 = null;
    } else {
        mNMBL009013 = in.readLong();
    }
}

public static final Creator<NewUser> CREATOR = new Creator<NewUser>() {
    @Override
    public NewUser createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new NewUser(in);
    }

    @Override
    public NewUser[] newArray(int size) {
        return new NewUser[size];
    }
};

public Long getBMBL009008() {
    return mBMBL009008;
}

public void setBMBL009008(Long bMBL009008) {
    mBMBL009008 = bMBL009008;
}

public String getCMBL009001() {
    return mCMBL009001;
}

public void setCMBL009001(String cMBL009001) {
    mCMBL009001 = cMBL009001;
}

public String getCMBL009003() {
    return mCMBL009003;
}

public void setCMBL009003(String cMBL009003) {
    mCMBL009003 = cMBL009003;
}

public String getCMBL009004() {
    return mCMBL009004;
}

public void setCMBL009004(String cMBL009004) {
    mCMBL009004 = cMBL009004;
}

public String getCMBL009005() {
    return mCMBL009005;
}

public void setCMBL009005(String cMBL009005) {
    mCMBL009005 = cMBL009005;
}

public String getCMBL009006() {
    return mCMBL009006;
}

public void setCMBL009006(String cMBL009006) {
    mCMBL009006 = cMBL009006;
}

public String getCMBL009010() {
    return mCMBL009010;
}

public void setCMBL009010(String cMBL009010) {
    mCMBL009010 = cMBL009010;
}

public String getCMBL009011() {
    return mCMBL009011;
}

public void setCMBL009011(String cMBL009011) {
    mCMBL009011 = cMBL009011;
}

public Long getNMBL009002() {
    return mNMBL009002;
}

public void setNMBL009002(Long nMBL009002) {
    mNMBL009002 = nMBL009002;
}

public Long getNMBL009007() {
    return mNMBL009007;
}

public void setNMBL009007(Long nMBL009007) {
    mNMBL009007 = nMBL009007;
}

public Long getNMBL009009() {
    return mNMBL009009;
}

public void setNMBL009009(Long nMBL009009) {
    mNMBL009009 = nMBL009009;
}

public Long getNMBL009012() {
    return mNMBL009012;
}

public void setNMBL009012(Long nMBL009012) {
    mNMBL009012 = nMBL009012;
}

public Long getNMBL009013() {
    return mNMBL009013;
}

public void setNMBL009013(Long nMBL009013) {
    mNMBL009013 = nMBL009013;
}


public NewUser(){

}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (mBMBL009008 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mBMBL009008);
    }
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009001);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009003);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009004);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009005);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009006);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009010);
    dest.writeString(mCMBL009011);
    if (mNMBL009002 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mNMBL009002);
    }
    if (mNMBL009007 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mNMBL009007);
    }
    if (mNMBL009009 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mNMBL009009);
    }
    if (mNMBL009012 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mNMBL009012);
    }
    if (mNMBL009013 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(mNMBL009013);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes, don't mark the field for serialization.

Comment: It is completely possible to have more fields in Model class than the JSON itself. But you cannot read values which are not present in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have extra fields in your model, but if server is not giving values for those fields then those extra fields will be initialized with default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSON you have to mark the field/member declarations as @Expose to consider it for parsing. Use `GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()`

Add extra fields and do not serialize those fields.